# Regular expression Group matching returns wrong value

Tags: java, regex

```
Regex=
 "^\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)(\\s+(\\S+(\\s+(\\S+))?))?(\\s+(\\S+))?\\s*";

input= "    1  ABC    DEF  GHI   JKL   PQR   ";
```

In the above input text the regular expression matches, but there is case where JKL can be word with space like "JKL MNO" so regular expression i have approched like optional

```
(\\s+(\\S+))?
```

While getting the group i am getting wrong value i.e

```
G1: 1 G2: ABC G3: DEF G4: GHI **G6: JKL PQR** G8:PQR
```

G6 Should be only JKL or JKL MNO as a word when MNO present, can you please figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Is PQR part also optional?

Comment: yes.PQR ,MNO or JKL MNO is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is, the inner `(\\s+(\\S+))?` of the part `(\\s+(\\S+(\\s+(\\S+))?))` reads up the `PQR` and the last part of your regex - `(\\s+(\\S+))?` being optional, ends up reading nothing.

Making the last part non-optional will solve the issue. However, you can avoid using so many capture groups if you don't intend to capture them, for e.g., spaces can be made non-capture - `(?:\\s+)`

So, you can probably change your regex to:

```
String str = "^\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)(?:\\s+(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?))?(?:\\s+(\\S+))\\s*";
```

Notice the part of concern here:

```
(?:\\s+(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?))?
```

As you can see there is only single capture group, which is enough to capture `JKL` and `JKL MNO` if present. In case you also want to capture `MNO` separately, make the inner `\\S+` also a capture group.

Comment: you made it mandatory.Where JKL   PQR   or JKL MNO PQR are optional. :)

Comment: Still don't understand which part is exactly optional.. I understand like - `JKL` is mandatory, `MNO` is optional and `PQR` is mandatory. Is it the correct requirement?

Comment: No,1  ABC    DEF  GHI  are compulsory and JKL MNO PQR is optional where JKL MNO is word with space it could be only JKL or JKL MNO .

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I got it.                                                                                 ^\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)(?:\\s+(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?))?(?:\\s+(\\S+))?\\s*

Answer (score 2):

Your observed behavior is what is expected for a regular expression.  A capture group starts with the opening paren for the group and ends with its ending paren.  If a capture group A contains a capture group B, then A will contain all of B.

That is for

`(\\s+(\\S+(\\s+(\\S+))?))?`

Matching against

```
   JKL PQR
```

group 1 is going to be

```
   JKL PQR
```

group 2 is going to be

```
JKL PQR
```

group 3 is going to be

```
 PQR
```

and group 4 is going to be

```
PQR
```

If you would like just JKL to be a group, you can use a combination of capture groups and non-capturing groups such as:

`(?:\\s+(?:(\\S+)(?:\\s+(\\S+))?))?`

Then group 1 will be `JKL` and group 2 will be `PQR`.

Answer (score 0):

If `PQR` is compulsory, removing the last `?` in `(\\s+(\\S+))?` will do.

It is because RegEx is greedy so it will take `PQR` in group 8 if the last part is optional (which is the problem).

The complete regex should be:
`"^\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)(\\s+(\\S+(\\s+(\\S+))?))?(\\s+(\\S+))\\s*"`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
^\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)(\\s+(\\S+(\\s+(\\S+))??))?(\\s+(\\S+))?\\s*$
```

The pattern uses a reluctant (non-greedy) quantifier `??`. This means that the group 7 is matched only when necessary.

When `" MNO"` is missing the group 7 is not matched at all. The group 6 contains only `" JKL"`.

If you use an *end of the string* anchor, you will force `" MNO"` to be matched by the group 7 even if this group is optional with a reluctant quantifier `??`. The group 6 contains `" JKL MNO"`

Without the reluctant quantifier, since the pattern is evaluated from left to right, `" PQR"` will be matched by group 7 (because the quantifier `?` is greedy by default) and the group 9 will match nothing since it is optional.

Note: without useless capturing groups, you can write:

```
^\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)(?:\\s+(?:(\\S+)(?:\\s+(\\S+))??))?(?:\\s+(\\S+))?\\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regular expressions that make my eyes swim I'd go for a split:

```
String[] toks = input.split( "\\s+" );
```

toks.length must be at least 4 so that we have `toks[0]` to `toks[3]`. Now:

- toks.length == 5: this should be "JKL"
- toks.length == 7: we have "v" in toks[4] and toks[5] and PQR in toks[6]

So what about toks.length == 6? Is the optional "MNO" stronger than the optional "PQR" or is it the other way round? In either case, you can decide more easily using the String[] and its length.

(I know that the number of spaces between "JKL" and "MNO" is lost this way. If it is really significant, it can be retrieved from the original string with small effort.)